# Highcharts: Parse multi-variable JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am trying to make a highcharts chart similar to the one in this demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic with json data, but I cant see how I can parse my json data in a sensible matter. My data is grouped by week-day, and has three categories. The following is an example:

```
{ "Monday": { "inv": 1126, "oppm": 276, "perc": "24.51" }, "Tuesday": { "inv": 1072, "oppm": 273, "perc": "25.47" }, "Wednesday": { "inv": 1032, "oppm": 271, "perc": "26.26" }, "Thursday": { "inv": 989, "oppm": 259, "perc": "26.19" }, "Friday": { "inv": 937, "oppm": 240, "perc": "25.61" } }
```

Is there a way to do this in a simple matter? Would it help if I changed my json data structure?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Solution:**

I found a not-too-complicated way of doing it, although I'm sure it could be done even easier if you know your JS. This solution works nicely with my JSON data anyway:

```
//Convert received AJAX data
success: function(data)
{                       
    cleanData = $.parseJSON(data);

    //Make some empty arrays for the categories and data
    days = Array();
    inv = Array();
    oppm = Array();
    perc = Array();

    //Iterate the data and fill in the new arrays
    $.each(cleanData, function(index, value) {
        days.push(index);
        inv.push(parseFloat(value['inv']));
        oppm.push(parseFloat(value['oppm']));
        perc.push(parseFloat(value['perc']));
    });

    //Use the new arrays in the chart
    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'div_chart',
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis:{
            categories: days,
            title: {
                text: 'Week day'
            }
        },
        series: [{
                name: 'Invited',
                data: inv
            }, {
                name: 'Met',
                data: oppm
            }, {
                name: '%',
                data: perc
            }],
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit that example in a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/

After looking at how that is formatted and how the data is added to the script, it seems that a couple of for loops would work out, but I think you need to change your JSON format slightly.

Here's how I'd do it (psueodocode):

```
var json = [
    {
        "day":"monday",
        "inv": 1126, 
        "oppm": 276, 
        "perc": "24.51"

    },
    {
         "day":"Tuesday",
         "inv": 1072, 
         "oppm": 273, 
         "perc": "25.47" 
    }
];
```

Then set the 'categories' option in the highcharts call by looping through this and getting all the days:

```
var myCategories;
var idx=0;
for (var key in json) {
    myCategories[idx]=json[key]['day'];
    idx++;
}
```

Then in the highcharts config:

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: myCategories
        },
```

And then all you need to do is the same thing again to set your datapoints in the highchars 'series' call, which will be a little bit more involved but the same idea.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, this is similar to what I found out

Comment: no problem, glad I could help. please either post your own solution as an answer and accept it or mark my answer as accepted (if it was good enough), so the question is marked as answered :)